# Can I use a searching algorithm between arrays?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

I have produced a plot of two arrays of the same size, the x axis being a time array with varying time steps and the y axis being a pre-calculated array of values. This is the plot below:

[image]

Up until this point, I have been searching for the time for when delta = 0 (apart from when time=0) . To do this, I have been manually going into the array to find at what step it reaches  this value (i.e. delta = 0 at step 3,000), then going into the time-value array and looking for the step with the same value (i.e. searching for the 3,000th step and retrieving the time).

Is there a way I can automate this and have it as an output rather than manually searching each time?

The base code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy import integrate

masses = [1, 1, 1]
r1, v1 = [0, 0], [-2*0.513938054919243, -2*0.304736003875733]
r2, v2 = [-1, 0], [0.513938054919243, 0.304736003875733]
r3, v3 = [1, 0], [0.513938054919243, 0.304736003875733]
u0 = np.concatenate([r1, v1, r2, v2, r3, v3])

def odesys(t, u):
    def force(a): return a / sum(a ** 2) ** 1.5
    r1, v1, r2, v2, r3, v3 = u.reshape([-1, 2])
    m1, m2, m3 = masses
    f12, f13, f23 = force(r1 - r2), force(r1 - r3), force(r2 - r3)
    a1, a2, a3 = -m2 * f12 - m3 * f13, m1 * f12 - m3 * f23, m1 * f13 + m2 * f23
    return np.concatenate([v1, a1, v2, a2, v3, a3])

# collect data
t_values = []
u_values = []
par_1_pos = []
d_values = []


# Time start, step, and finish point
t0, tf, t_step = 0, 18, 0.0001
nsteps = int((tf - t0) / t_step)

solution = integrate.RK45(odesys, t0, u0, tf, max_step=t_step)

# The loop for running the Runge-Kutta method over some time period.
u_values.append(solution.y)
t_values.append(t0)
par_1_pos.append(((solution.y[0] - u0[0])**2 + (solution.y[1] - u0[1])**2)**0.5)

d_values.append(((solution.y[0] - u0[0])**2 + (solution.y[1] - u0[1])**2)**0.5 + 
                ((solution.y[4] - u0[4])**2 + (solution.y[5] - u0[5])**2)**0.5 + 
                ((solution.y[8] - u0[8])**2 + (solution.y[9] - u0[9])**2)**0.5 +
                ((solution.y[2] - u0[2])**2 + (solution.y[3] - u0[3])**2)**0.5 +
                ((solution.y[6] - u0[6])**2 + (solution.y[7] - u0[7])**2)**0.5 +
                ((solution.y[10] - u0[10])**2 + (solution.y[11] - u0[11])**2)**0.5)

for step in range(nsteps):
    solution.step()
    u_values.append(solution.y)
    t_values.append(solution.t)
    
    par_1_pos.append(((solution.y[0] - u0[0])**2 + (solution.y[1] - u0[1])**2)**0.5)
    
    d_values.append(((solution.y[0] - u0[0])**2 + (solution.y[1] - u0[1])**2)**0.5 + 
                ((solution.y[4] - u0[4])**2 + (solution.y[5] - u0[5])**2)**0.5 + 
                ((solution.y[8] - u0[8])**2 + (solution.y[9] - u0[9])**2)**0.5 +
                ((solution.y[2] - u0[2])**2 + (solution.y[3] - u0[3])**2)**0.5 +
                ((solution.y[6] - u0[6])**2 + (solution.y[7] - u0[7])**2)**0.5 +
                ((solution.y[10] - u0[10])**2 + (solution.y[11] - u0[11])**2)**0.5)
    
    # break loop after modelling is finished
    if solution.status == 'finished':
        break

# Plotting of the individual particles
u = np.asarray(u_values).T

# Plot for The trajectory of the three bodies over the time period
plt.plot(u[0], u[1], '-o', lw=1, ms=3, label="body 1")
plt.plot(u[4], u[5], '-x', lw=1, ms=3, label="body 2")
plt.plot(u[8], u[9], '-s', lw=1, ms=3, label="body 3")

plt.title('Trajectories of the three bodies')
plt.xlabel('X Position')
plt.ylabel('Y Position')

plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
plt.close()

# Plot for d(delta_t) values
plt.plot(t_values, d_values)

plt.title('Delta number for the three bodies')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Delta')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
plt.close()

# Plot of distance between P1 and IC
plt.plot(t_values, par_1_pos)

plt.title('Plot of distance between P1 and IC')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Distance from origin')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: Usually plot data will have a coordinate system as input, meaing a list of (x-axis, y-axis) tuples. It sounds like your plot data has `steps` on the x-axis. Are you sure there is no funciton from step => time?
Also can you share any code that you use to crrate this plot? Any solution that automates this process will depend on however you're doing what you're doing

Comment: *"searching for the 3,000th step"*: that is phrased as if that represents a lot of work. But if it is an array, then with `arr[3000]` you have the desired value in one go, no?

Comment: @Glubus The code that I use has a varying time step so the values of x are constantly changing (this is because of the integration method I'm using. The code is quite substantial but I'll upload it above.

Comment: @trincot The problem is repeatability. I will be constantly changing the values of delta which sometimes may not equal zero. The point is to obtain the step in which it reaches zero, if at all.

Comment: From what I can see in your code, it looks like d_values and t_values are always the same length, meaning that if the nth value in d_values is 0, that means you need the nth value in t_values. Is this correct? If so, then I would write a function that searches in d_values for 0's, keeping the index (= position in d_values), and using it to obtain the corresponding value in t_values.

Comment: You should not control the accuracy of the solver with `max_step`. That parameter serves in situations where local features of short duration occur that the solver would else jump over. Use the error tolerances `atol` and `rtol` to set accuracy goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life less complicated, use the provided time-loop routine `solve_ivp`.

You want to compute a point of minimal distance to the initial point `u0`. This is a point where the derivative of the distance goes from negative to positive. The derivative of the square of the distance is the dot product of tangent vector and difference vector. Close to the minimum it makes not much difference if the tangent vector is of the point or of the initial point.

Thus define an event of the "counting" type

```python
Tu0 = odesys(t0,u0)
def dist_plane(u): return Tu0.dot(u-u0)
event0 = lambda t,u: dist_plane(u)
event0.direction = 1
```

and call the solver with its standard stepper `RK45` and all the parameters

```python
solution = solve_ivp(odesys, [t0,tf], u0, events=event0, atol=1e-10, rtol=1e-11)

u_values = solution.y.T
t_values = solution.t

def norm(u): return sum(u**2)**0.5

def dist_1(u): return norm(u[:2]-u0[:2])
def dist_all(u): return sum(norm(uu) for uu in (u-u0).reshape([-1,2]))

par_1_pos = [ dist_1(uu) for uu in u_values]
d_values = [dist_all(uu) for uu in u_values]
d_plane = [dist_plane(uu) for uu in u_values]
```

The last lines so you can do all the plots as before.

For the minimal however you just have to evaluate the event fields of the returned structure. Printing the distance measures results in a table

```python
for tt,uu in zip(solution.t_events[0], solution.y_events[0]):
    print(rf"|{tt:12.8f} | {dist_1(uu):12.8f} | {dist_all(uu):12.8f} | {dist_plane(uu):12.8f} |")
```

| t | dist pos1 | dist all | dist deriv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00000000 | 0.00000000 | 0.00000000 | 0.00000000 |
| 2.81292221 | 0.58161236 | 3.54275380 | 0.00000000 |
| 4.17037860 | 0.35583855 | 5.77531098 | 0.00000000 |
| 5.71976151 | 0.63111430 | 3.98764796 | -0.00000000 |
| 8.66440460 | 0.00000019 | 3.73331800 | 0.00000000 |
| 11.60904921 | 0.63111445 | 3.98764485 | -0.00000000 |
| 13.15843018 | 0.35583804 | 5.77530951 | 0.00000000 |
| 14.51588605 | 0.58161284 | 3.54275265 | -0.00000000 |
| 17.32881023 | 0.00000078 | 0.00000328 | 0.00000000 |

This shorter list should be easier to search for the global minimum.

Comment: This works seamlessly with my current code, thank you! 

The only issue I currently see is the change in the time mesh, as before I would change the value for t_step to increase the overall three body trajectory accuracy, but doing this now seems to accomplish nothing, what would be the correct approach with the current changes?

Comment: If you use a solver with adaptive step size then the accuracy is controlled by the absolute and relative error tolerances, the <local error>/<step size> is controlled to be about `max(atol, rtol*norm(y))`.

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays are the same length, you can keep the index of your search.. Otherwise, you may be able to use the percentage through of the array as your starting point for the search of the second array. (position 1000 in an array of 3000 is 1/3rd, so about position 1166 when mapped into an array of 3500)

If you want *any* value (or there will only be one), you can bisect the data with a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

If you want the *first* and there may be more than one value, you'll have to do a [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search).

Answer (score 0):

1. **if your `x` values are time steps**

   then convert them to time values first by summing them up (but for that you need the array is sorted by time first which would be insane if not already in this case).
2. **if your `x` values are sorted**

   then use binary search. if not use linear search.
3. **if your searched value is not exactly present in your data**

   but you have points below and above you can simply interpolate it from closest neighbors (linear,cubic or higher 2D interpolation) but for that is best if your searched array is sorted otherwise you will have hard time getting valid closest neighbors.